Browser Console Errors in SharePoint After Custom Development
I hope you're doing well. I'm reaching out for some guidance on an issue I'm facing in SharePoint. After implementing some custom development, I've noticed several errors appearing in the browser console. These errors don't seem to be related to my custom code.
I've attached a screenshot for reference.
Any advice on how to troubleshoot or resolve these errors would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your support!
Best regards,
Hassan Nawaz

